# Can't open Bootstrap hamburger dropdown or other <li> with dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had made a bootstrap menu in Wordpress, it looks perfect - but I can't open any dropdown items or the hamburger icon toggle-menu.

Yeah.. I had read many other topics about it, but I can make it works!

Here is my JS enqueues:

```
function wpt_register_js() {
    wp_register_script('jquery.bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.bootstrap.min');
    wp_register_script('jquery.bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', 'jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.bootstrap');
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpt_register_js' );
```

And here is my navigation:

```
<header class="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
            ) );
            ?>
        </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: check your console in developer tools (f12).do you get any errors like jquery or bootstrap not getting loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import JQuery in your project.

Add these lines to your index.html head:

```
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```